# Paraview: Diffrent color on contour plot and legend

Tags: paraview

There are differences between color on contour plot and legend. Is it possible to change that?
[image]

Comment: Try turning on the "Additional Headlight." In the properties panel search box, type "Lights". You should see an option named Lights with an edit button next to it. Click the edit button, and in the resulting dialog box, turn on the "Additional Headlight" checkbox.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped.:)